# Valid commands to be used in backticks in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, backticks

Consider the two commands,

```
command1="mysql -umyuser -pmypassword -e \"show databases;\";"
command2="cat stackoverflow.txt"
```

The strings are formed as follows,

```
echo ${command1} -> mysql -umyuser -pmypassword -e "show databases;";
echo ${command2} -> cat stackoverflow.txt
```

**My aim is to run the command from a variable and store it's result in another**.

So what I do is,

```
result1=`${command1}`
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'databases;";'
```

BUT,

```
result2=`${command2}`
```

works perfectly fine.

When using `$()` instead of backticks the commands behave the same.

Both, of these commands work perfectly fine when run directly in backquotes instead of a variable.

Why this different behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
command1="mysql -umyuser -pmypassword -e \"show databases;\";"
```

fails because of word splitting.  When you say `$command1`, the shell would interpret it as:

```
mysql -umuuser -pmypassword -e '"show' 'databases;";'
```

So the parameter passed to `-e` option is `"show` and not what you thought.

Make use of functions instead:

```
mycommand() {
  mysql -umyuser -pmypassword -e "show databases;"
}
```

In the second case, the shell is simply reading the contents of the file and executing it.  As such, it works.

You may also want to refer to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) in the manual.  Also see: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).